# Error message while calculating if number is perfect power

Tags: javascript, math, logarithm

I'm trying to determine if a number "n" is a perfect power. I've created the following code to work through this problem.

```
var isPP = function(n) {
  console.log(n);
  for (let base = 2; base < n; base++) {

    //Change of base formula used to change natural log to log base "base"
      let exp = Math.log(n) / Math.log(base);

   //If "exp" variable is integer, return array containing base and exponent 
     if (Math.pow(base,exp) === n) {
       return [base,exp];
     }
   }

  return null;
}
```

This passes every test except for one random test (ex: when n = 14618, the error message reads "returned not null on non-perfect power 14618"). The same result occurs when the random test provides an "n" of 62383.

I'm not sure why the code is passing every test except for this last one. Could it be that the numbers are too large for JS?

Comment: this fails for n=9

Answer (score 0):

Here are some small changes I've made to your code

```
var isPP = function(n){
  for (let base = 2; base <= n/2; base++) { //start at 2
    for (let exp = 2; exp <= n/2; exp++) {
      let current = Math.pow(base,exp);
      if (current == n)
        return [base, exp];
      if (current > n)
        break; //break when found to create a 'best case' runtime
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

As @Isaac stated before, your code also fails for `n=9`. Your error reads this because 14618 is not a perfect power. Same with 62383.